# jquery autocomplete with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am trying to get jQuery autocomplete in a textbox. But I don't seem to be able to display the data from my `JsonResult` in the view, I checked with firebug and verfied that the data is transferred from server, just doesn't disply in the TextBox. I don't get any errors.

Here's my code :

```
public JsonResult search(string term)
    {


        // string prefixText =SearchString;
        var FamilyLastName = _repository.FamilySearch(term);
        var data=FamilyLastName.ToList();
        return Json(data);//.Select(x => new { label = x, ID = x }));
    }


@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <label for="SearchString">My Autocomplete:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="SearchString" id="SearchString"  autocomplete="off" />


    }


 <script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function () {

     var param = { "searchstring": $("#SearchString").val() };
     $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
         autoFocus: true,
         source: function (request, response) {
             // call your Action
             $.ajax({
                 url:'search?term=' + $("#SearchString").val(),
               // data:"{'term':'" +$("#SearchString").val() + "'}",
                 dataType: 'json',
                 method: "post",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                 success: function (data) {

                     return{
                         label:data.FamilyLastName
                     };
                         },

                 select:
                     function (event, ui) {
                         $('#SearchString').val(ui.item.label);
                         return false;
            },

             });
         },
          minLength: 1,// requ
```

Comment: set also value in success like value:data.FamilyLastName

Comment: still not working,  I changed success function  like this   to see I get the data and yes I do get the data back  in an alert  box, I just can't get it to work inside the textbox  :            success:     function (data) {
                         alert(data);
                     }

Comment: I got it working  , I changed success to                                             success: function (data) {
                         response($.map(data,function(item){
                             return{label:item,value:item};
                             
                         }))

                     }